# VB.Net Limiting Checked in the datagridview and get data from it to label

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

Please help me. 
I have some problem on my vb code. I have a Datagridview with Checkbox column in it. My system is a library system. i want the user to borrow only 2 books. and my problem is.
1. I want to limit the user to checked only to 2.
2. And when the row was check i want to get some data for example the book title and the author and put it to a label.

Please help me.

```
 Public Sub BorrowBook()

    Dim Message As String = String.Empty
    Dim Message1 As String = String.Empty
    Dim Message2 As String = String.Empty
    Dim Message3 As String = String.Empty
    Dim Message4 As String = String.Empty
        Dim Message5 As String = String.Empty

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Form5.DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("checkBoxColumn").Value)
            isSelected += 1
            If isSelected = 1 Then
                Message = row.Cells("BookID").Value.ToString()
                Message1 = row.Cells("CallNumber").Value.ToString()
                Message2 = row.Cells("Title").Value.ToString()

            ElseIf isSelected = 2 Then
                Message3 = row.Cells("BookID").Value.ToString()
                Message4 = row.Cells("CallNumber").Value.ToString()
                Message5 = row.Cells("Title").Value.ToString()

            End If
        Next
        Form5.Label17.Text = Message
        Form5.Label25.Text = Message1
        Form5.Label21.Text = Message2
        Form5.Label20.Text = Message3
        Form5.Label26.Text = Message4
        Form5.Label19.Text = Message5
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Problem let me answer the second one because I need to know first one, here it is.

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
         Form5.Label17.Text = DataGridView.Item(0, i).Value
         Form5.Label25.Text= DataGridView.Item(1, i).Value
         Form5.Label21.Text = DataGridView.Item(2, i).Value
         Form5.Label19.Text = DataGridView.Item(3, i).Value
    End Sub
```

it is only an example you can put this code either in `Button Click` or `DataGridview Click` then count your columns starting from 0 and replace the code above with the number of your desired column example.

`DataGridView.Item(0, i).Value \\If 0 = BookID`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `List` (as Form level variable) and, after checking `If List.Contains(RowId)` (where RowId is an unique index of the row) `Then Remove` it from the List `OrElse` check `If List.Count < 2` and `Add` the RowId to the List.

After that you can check the rows having the Id into the `List` and uncheck the ones removed from the list.