# How to Get Checked row data from datagridview to Label

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have some problem with my code. I'm using vb with mysql as database. i also have datagridview where the frist column is a checkedboxcolumn. All i want is: When the user check the checkbox some data will show automatically in the label.

i have here my codes. Actually it is running. but the problem is the data that i first checked will show when i check 2nd checkbox.

```vb
Dim counter As Integer = 0
For Each oRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(oRow.Cells("checkBoxColumn").Value)
    If Me.DataGridView1.Focused = True Then
        If isSelected = True Then
            counter += 1
            If counter = 1 Then
                oRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                Label17.Text = oRow.Cells("Book_ID").Value.ToString()
                Label25.Text = oRow.Cells("Call_Number").Value.ToString()
                Label21.Text = oRow.Cells("Title").Value.ToString()

                If oRow.Cells("checkBoxColumn").Value = False Then
                    Label17.Text = ""
                    Label25.Text = ""
                    Label21.Text = ""
                End If
            ElseIf counter = 2 Then
                oRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
                Label20.Text = oRow.Cells("Book_ID").Value.ToString()
                Label26.Text = oRow.Cells("Call_Number").Value.ToString()
                Label19.Text = oRow.Cells("Title").Value.ToString()
                oRow.Cells("checkBoxColumn").Value = False
                MsgBox("You can Borrow 2 Books at a Time")

            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How is this substantially different than [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41373925/1070452)?

Comment: My last question is how to limit the checked in the checkedbox. and i already get the code

Comment: Plsss Help me. T_T..